# How to render a bumpy texture in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting

I'm trying to render a simple chair with a textured/bumpy plastic seat. The problem is that cycles will smooth out the bumps in the final render. I've tried different amounts of denoising, and I've tried no denoising with higher sampling counts. Both will smooth out the final result. I don't want the whole image to be noisy because the chair legs are meant to be smooth.

Additionally, the back legs of the chair have black lines around the bottom edges. Could this be because I've made the background transparent? Is this a lighting issue?

[image: burgundy chair with smoothed out plastic seat and black lines on legs]

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: The back legs could be a normal interpolation issue, try including another loop cut near the bottom.

Comment: I could try that, but the legs render properly from different angles and they look fine when rendered with the Eevee render engine...

Comment: For clarification: The model is an STL file made in solidworks. My work has asked me to figure out how to texture and render it using blender, but I have no previous experience with this...

Comment: Hello, how many samples did you render with ? Try increasing it, and try disabling denoising, it usually smoothes out bumps on textures. The leg thing may come from a displacement map that is too strong, try to lower the displacement strength if the material has one

Comment: I guess the black lines might be because of improper UV maps..additionally to address the main issue can u please elaborate using some more pics depicting issue or share the blend file